# "Живёт, питаясь только плодами". Нужно ли обособлять оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

**"Всевластие выпадает на долю тех, кто живёт, питаясь только плодами и кореньями".**

Постоянно сомневаюсь: не примыкает ли деепричастие к глаголу, обозначая образ действия?

Answer (score 4):

Питание - не образ жизни, поэтому нет тесной связи с глаголом, оборот обособляется.

Сравните: живёт играючи.

Answer (score 0):

Живёт (что делая?) питаясь только плодами и кореньями - обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом (деепричастием питаясь и зависимыми словами) 
"ПитаЯсь" образовано от глагола "питаться", суффикс деепричастия - Я.
Сравните: живёт играючи (играючи - не распространено), кроме вопроса ЧТО ДЕЛАЯ?, отвечает на дополнительный вопрос КАК? Следовательно, может рассматриваться и как наречие, поэтому не обособляется.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что оборот обособляется на "общих основаниях".
Попробуйте заменить "питаясь" на синонимичные деепричастия — *насыщаясь, довольствуясь, употребляя*. В этом случае вопрос "нужна ли запятая?" отпадает сам собой.

*Он не замечает перед собой тигра, который **живет, питаясь чужой плотью,** и не видит, что позади притаился охотник, готовый пронзить его острыми стрелами.*
[**Шримад-Бхагаватам. Песнь четвертая**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=eL42DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1534&lpg=PT1534&dq=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82,%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E,&source=bl&ots=4jVJ_TyvaU&sig=4qaUTVrX-nl9uDV-JFve8bfJAgo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxqomG9oXZAhXQalAKHXDTD1wQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C&f=false)

*Приходящий сюда ссыльный **живет, питаясь кислым молоком** с тарою (древесною корою) и изредка рыбою...*
С. В. Максимов. Сибирь и каторга

*Ты, например, **живешь, питаясь олениной,** а олень **живет, питаясь змейкой**...*
С. С. Неретина. Тропы и концепты
[Змейка — змеиная трава]